# Using dd to do a bare-metal restoration w/ stored individual partitions

Tags: partition, backup, dd

I have a disk that I make regular backups of. The disk is made of a few different partitions. Previously I've been using the dd command to back up /dev/sdX all at once and it's all gone very well. I also use these backups to sometimes clone the disk to another disk.

However, it turns out that one of those partitions is very large and changes very infrequently. It would be better if I could just back up the individual partitions so that the backups can be smaller.

Of course dd can just back up /dev/sdX1, /dev/sdX2, etc. However: I still would like to be able to clone these backups to a new disk from bare metal. I can currently do that very well with my backup of the entire disk, however things are somewhat different if I am only backing up partitions.

How do I do this? Do I need to store something like the MBR as well?

Answer (score 0):

With dd on Linux it does not matter whether the data is being transferred between files or block-devices.

I assume, when you create a backup, you store it in a disk image like this:

```
dd bs=128M if=/dev/sda of=backup.dd
```

Note: This will also copy the MBR and GPT data since they reside in the first 512 (MBR) or 16k (GPT) bytes of the disk.

The nice thing in Linux: You can use the image file just like a block-device using a "virtual" loop-device:

```
udisksctl loop-setup --file backup.dd
```

Now your backup appears in the file manager – just like an external would do. It is usually called `/dev/loopX` with `X` being a number. The loop-device also has partitions `/dev/loopXp1` and alike.

You can now update a single partition of the backup:

```
dd bs=128M if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/loopXp1
```

After the update, "unmount" the file:

```
udisksctl loop-delete --block-device /dev/loopX
```

But wait – there is more: Using specialized file-system tools, you can speed-up the update by only copying the used parts of the partition, skipping all the empty space. I can recommend these (I do not know others from the top of my head):

- ext2/3/4: `e2image -rap /dev/sda1 /dev/loopXp1`
- NTFS: `ntfsclone --overwrite /dev/loopXp1 /dev/sda1`

But wait – there is more: Depending on the utilization, you may also use rsync to update the backup. For this, it is necessary to mount the file-system in the backup file (after loop-setup, bevore loop-delete):

```
udisksctl mount -b /dev/loopXp1
rsync -av wherever/dev/sda1/is/mounted/ wherever/dev/loopXp1/is/mounted/
udisksctl unmount -b /dev/loopXp1
```

Comment: Thanks, interesting ideas - one question is, if I'm going with something like rsync, what would the point be of using dd at all? I could just rsync to some folder directly.

Comment: rsync analyses every file individually. When copying a file-system which is almost full with a large amount of small files, there will be a considerable overhead. rsync might even exhaust your RAM trying to keep track of all the file information. In this scenario, dd will be faster since it can transfer large chunks of data, possibly transferring hundreds of files in one operation (it does not even "see" the files, just blocks of data). This is just an example, but you get the general idea.

Comment: It is my understanding that gpt stores GUID for each partition in the primary partition table at beginning of drive, in the partition and the backup partition table at end of drive. Those GUIDs must stay in sync. Or you may need to use gdisk to repair is out of sync. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436006 &
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2368992

Comment: @oldfred That is correct. A full-disk dd will copy both, the main and backup GPT. None of the operations described here will change the partitions so no GPT-related problems are to be expected.